# CGI not printing under MAMP

Tags: c, macos, printing, cgi, mamp

I'm using MAMP (so on Mac) and working on CGI in C. I've made the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n");
    printf("Hello <b> in bold</b>\n");
    FILE *f = popen("lp -", "w");
    if (!f)
    {
       printf("<b>ERROR</b>\n");    
       exit(1);
    }
   fprintf(f, "This will be send to printer");
   return 0;
}
```

When I run it under Terminal (after compiling of course), I see the text "Hello in bold" and the output of "This will be send to printer" is correctlty send to the printer.
But when I put the CGI in cgi-bin folder in MAMP and call the CGI, the text is correctly displayed (meaning the CGI is correctly executed), but there is no output to the printer.
Why? Any idea?

Comment: `f` not being NULL does not yet mean `lp` can print, it just means `popen` can start it. Try opening with "r+" mode string, so you can both read and write from `f`. The fgets from `f`, and print it. Might see something like: "lp: Error - no default destination available." That can help you diagnose it perhaps.

Comment: In terminal try doing: `which lp` and use the output absolute path (eg. `/usr/bin/lp`) in `popen`.

Comment: You should close whatever you opened.

Comment: MikeCAT i've add the missing pclose() but no change.

Comment: You never call fflush. Could it be exiting without sending actually sending anything to the pipe.

Comment: Jarra, I tried adding fflush() without any succes. In fact what I don't understand is that it works perfectly under Terminal, but NOT under MAMP.

Comment: @BuellaGábor "The popen() function opens a process by creating a pipe, forking, and invoking the shell.  Since a pipe is by definition unidirectional, the type argument may specify only reading or writing, not both; the resulting stream is correspondingly read-only or write-only."

Comment: @Peter the CGI will probably run under the permissions of the web server user (apache?), not you; and the web server user is not allowed to print by default. In terminal try changing to that user (`sudo su apache`) then executing lpr.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It does work, I tried it before writing that comment. The op specifies OSX in the question. from `man popen` on OSX: "Historically, popen() was implemented with a unidirectional pipe; hence, many implementations of popen() only allow the mode argument to
     specify reading or writing, not both.  Because popen() is now implemented using a bidirectional pipe, the mode argument may request a bidirectional data flow."

Comment: I don't know MAMAP, but Antti is likely right about the permission issue. Also, if it is CGI, you can probably just try running a shell script.

Comment: @BuellaGábor I stand corrected. However it is very likely that whatever the error message is if any, it will be written to the `stderr` and thus not available from `popen`. The error message could be available in Apache error log.

Comment: @Antti Haapala I think you're right. I'm investigating in this way and I start to think that using MAMP turn things harder. When I run MAMP and look at process, I see MAMP running as "maison", but I can't see any apache process. When I have a look at apache2/httpd.conf it seems to run as "_www".... So i'ts a bit confusing. I tried to "sudo" Apache, or only my CGI without any succes. Still investigating.

Answer (score 0):

It works!
First thanks a lot to those who had put coments, helping a lot.
I'll explain what I've done as it can be useful outside of this CGI problem.
Running the CGI (code in the question) from the desktop of the Mac was OK. Running as CGI give no printer output but the text "Hello **in bold**" was correctly displayed on the web page.
Having a look at the Apache Erro log (tail on Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log), thanks to Antti Haapala, I see:

```
 lp\xc2\xa0: erreur - aucune destination par d\xc3\xa9faut disponible.
```

Meaning "No default destination avaible". After performing "which lp" (thanks to I'L'I) I get /usr/bin/lp, set it in my popen() call and run the CGI.
And I get in the error log:

```
 /usr/bin/lp\xc2\xa0: erreur - aucune destination par d\xc3\xa9faut disponible.
```

So same answer... After searching I find a strange point: when I run the CGI from the desktop (so clicking on it), it prints, using my default printer (EPSON M105) which I set in the Preferences panel of my Mac. Meaning when you use popen(lp) from the desktop, it works. But when you use it in a CGI throught Apache, for the CGI there is no default printer, meaning Mac OSX seems to have two default printer setting.
So, under Terminal, I've done:

```
   lpstat -a
```

to get the list of the printer available. Then, just do:

```
   lpoptions -d PRINTERNAME
```

replacing "PRINTERNAME" by the name of the printer you get from the prievious comande, to set the default printer for "lp".

Then run again the CGI. Now, it prints but.... give an Internal Server Error!!

After seaching again, I find that using lp with "w" output the name of the printer. Strangly, its seems the ouput is done while performing the pclose() as if you don't put the pclose() you don't have the Error 500. 
To use the pclose() and avoid this ouput , you must use "r+" in popen() rather than "w".

The good code is:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main(void)
 {
     int status;

    printf("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n");
    printf("Hello test 7  <b> in bold</b>\n");

    FILE *f = popen("lp -", "r+");

    if (!f)
     {
        printf("<b>ERROR</b>\n");   
        exit(1);
     }

    fprintf(f, "Text that will be send to the printer");
    fflush(f);
    status = pclose(f);

    printf("Hello <b> in bold 2</b>\n");
    return 0;
 }
```

Hope this will help.